# Using numcases environment in align environment

Tags: alignment, cases

I am using multiple cases environments, and to align them I use align environment. Everything looks as it should.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\delta(a, b) &=\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
     &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z), \\
     &f(a, b) + g(b, c), \\
     &f(b, c) + g(a, b))
\end{aligned} & \text{condition 1,} \\
\begin{aligned}
\min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
     &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z)), \\
\end{aligned} & \text{condition 2,} \\    
0 & \text{condition 3}\\
+\infty & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases} \\
\psi(a, b) &=
\begin{cases}
\min(f(a, b), f(b, c), f(c, d)) & \text{condition 1}, \\
\psi(a, b) & \text{condition 2}, \\
\delta(b, c) & \text{condition 3}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result with cases environment]

However, as soon as I change cases to numcases everything goes wrong and I receive tons of TeX errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\delta(a, b) &=\begin{numcases}
\begin{aligned}
\min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
     &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z), \\
     &f(a, b) + g(b, c), \\
     &f(b, c) + g(a, b))
\end{aligned} & \text{condition 1,} \\
\begin{aligned}
\min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
     &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z)), \\
\end{aligned} & \text{condition 2,} \\    
0 & \text{condition 3}\\
+\infty & \text{otherwise,}
\end{numcases} \\
\psi(a, b) &=
\begin{numcases}
\min(f(a, b), f(b, c), f(c, d)) & \text{condition 1}, \\
\psi(a, b) & \text{condition 2}, \\
\delta(b, c) & \text{condition 3}
\end{numcases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Not correct result with numcases]

Here's the pastebin with overleaf raw error log https://pastebin.com/BMzMZKeQ

I assume this might be due to numcases also providing an alignment by default. How can I change the code to fix this and get the same result with numcases as with cases?

Comment: It is probably a good idea to cite the error you get instead of showing an image. The PDF outcome from a compilation with errors cannot be trusted anyway.

Comment: Additionally did you post the wrong second MWE? As the MWE posted has no issues.

Comment: Fixed second MWE, added pastebin with raw error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two `empheq` environments, with the help of `eqparbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqmath}[3][c]{%
  % #1 = alignment, default c, #2 = label, #2 = math material
  \eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle#3$}%
}
\newcommand{\eqtext}[3][c]{%
  % #1 = alignment, default c, #2 = label, #2 = text material
  \eqmakebox[#2][#1]{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={\eqmath[r]{A}{\delta(a,b)=}\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
&\eqmath[l]{B}{\begin{aligned}
\min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
     &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z), \\
     &f(a, b) + g(b, c), \\
     &f(b, c) + g(a, b))
\end{aligned}} &\qquad& \eqtext[l]{C}{condition 1,} \\
&\eqmath[l]{B}{\begin{aligned}
\min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
     &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z)), \\
\end{aligned}} &\qquad& \eqtext[l]{C}{condition 2,} \\    
&\eqmath[l]{B}{0} &\qquad& \eqtext[l]{C}{condition 3}\\
&\eqmath[l]{B}{+\infty} &\qquad& \eqtext[l]{C}{otherwise,}
\end{empheq}
\begin{empheq}[left={\eqmath[r]{A}{\psi(a,b)=}\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
&\eqmath[l]{B}{\min(f(a, b), f(b, c), f(c, d))} &\qquad& \eqtext[l]{C}{condition 1,} \\
&\eqmath[l]{B}{\psi(a, b)} &\qquad& \eqtext[l]{C}{condition 2,} \\
&\eqmath[l]{B}{\delta(b, c)} &\qquad& \eqtext[l]{C}{condition 3}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The labels `A`, `B` and `C` are arbitrary. You need *different* labels if you use again the tricks with `\eqmath` and `\eqtext`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you cannot align two `numcases`-environments. Your code has two problems:

- `numcases` needs an argument, in your case e.g. `\delta(a,b)=` which is prepended to the case distinction.
- `numcases` does not seem to work inside any equation-environment.

I fixed your code so that at least `numcases` works, but until now I have no solution for the problem of aligning them. On the first sight they seem to be aligned, but they are not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}
   \begin{numcases}{\delta(a,b)=}
      \begin{aligned}
         \min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
         &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z), \\
         &f(a, b) + g(b, c), \\
         &f(b, c) + g(a, b))
      \end{aligned} & \text{condition 1,} \\
      \begin{aligned}
         \min(&1 + f(x, y) + d(x, y) \\
         &1 + f(x, z) + d(x, z)), \\
      \end{aligned} & \text{condition 2,} \\    
      0 & \text{condition 3}\\
      +\infty & \text{otherwise,}
   \end{numcases}
   \begin{numcases}{\psi(a, b) =}
      \min(f(a, b), f(b, c), f(c, d)) & \text{condition 1}, \\
      \psi(a, b) & \text{condition 2}, \\
      \delta(b, c) & \text{condition 3}
   \end{numcases}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I had before, unfortunately as soon as you change conditions to have different lengths, nothing is aligned anymore.

Comment: I know, that's what I wrote below the bullet points `;-)` As I said, currently I do not have a solution for the alignment-problem, but at least you have numbered cases now.

Comment: I guess I'll have to pick either alignment or numbered cases :)

Comment: I think the problem is the same like with two `align`-environments: in this case you cannot do any alignment between them, too. In this case you could play around with things like `\begin{numcases}{\hspace{-1cm}\mathllap{\psi(a, b) ={}}}`, but I would not do that if I were you.